# Calculating element-wise powers using vectors in MATLAB

Tags: vectors, matlab

I'm trying to calculate the following using vectors:

The goal is to have a vector that looks as follows:

\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           10^1 \\
           10^2 \\
           \vdots \\
           10^k
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Where k=50.

I'm quite new to MATLAB so I thought about doing the following:
\begin{align}
    k &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 & 2 & \dots & k
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    n &= \begin{bmatrix}
           10 \\ 10 \\ \vdots \\ 10
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

The MATLAB code to compute the answer would then be:

n = ones(20, 1)*10

k = 1:20

y = n.^k

But that code doesn't seem to perform element-wise power as I expected. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I could go about doing this without having to use any for loops that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10.^[1:50]
```

Hope to help you

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much that worked perfectly :)